# how to check key exists in nsdictionary swift and get result in array

Tags: json, swift3, nsdictionary

I get value from key in objective C but in swift i don't know **how to do it?**

```
 NSDictionary *dictResult = [NSJSONSerialization
                                JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

if ([dictResult objectForKey:@"wsResponse"]!=nil)
{
     for (NSDictionary *dict in [[dictResult valueForKey:@"wsResponse"]valueForKey:@"Bhaktamar"])
     {
            objBean=[[Beandata alloc]init];
            objBean.strcontent=[dict objectForKey:@"content"];
            objBean.strtitle=[dict objectForKey:@"title"];

            [dataBase insertJsonData:@"BhaktamarData" Title:objBean.strtitle Content:objBean.strcontent];

     }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

**JSON ARRAY**

```
{"wsResponse":{"Bhaktamar":[{"content":"atipati nath","title":"atipatinath"},{"content":"atipati nath","title":"atipatinath"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Swift 3 equivalent is:

```
do {
    if let dictResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:jsonData, options:[]) as? [String:Any] {
        if let wsResponse = dictResult["wsResponse"] as? [String:Any], let shlock = wsResponse["Bhaktamar"] as? [[String:Any]] {
            for dict in shlock {
                objBean = Beandata()
                objBean.strcontent = dict["content"] as? String ?? ""
                objBean.strtitle = dict["title"] as? String ?? ""
                dataBase.insertJsonData("BhaktamarData", Title:objBean.strtitle, Content:objBean.strcontent)
            }
        }
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

The syntax for the insert line is probably different (there must be a parameter label for the first parameter).

PS: Consider that the variable `objBean` is initialized in the repeat loop but actually unused.

Comment: **What** is not working? The code is the 1:1 equivalent of the objc code.

Comment: code is equivalent but i run this code in swift break from this line **if let wsResponse = dictResult["wsResponse"] as? [String:Any] ,let shlock = wsResponse["Bhaktamar"] as? [[String:Any]]**

Comment: `wsResponse["Bhaktamar"]` is not `wsResponse["Shlock"]` as in the code. Please read the JSON carefully and check the keys and types: `[]` is array, `{}` is dictionary.

Comment: sorry wsResponse["Bhaktamar"] is right, i will change in code

Comment: still didn't get result i  tiered updated question (array)

Comment: The JSON parsing is supposed to work. Print `dict` in the repeat loop. It might be something wrong with `objBean` and how it's inserted in the data base.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129417/discussion-between-seggy-and-vadian).